# How to resolve: "Unregister-ScheduledTask : The system cannot find the file specified." error in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have created a New-SchedukedTask. When I try to unregister it, I am facing the below error. I am new to powershell. Kindly help me..

```
PS C:\> $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument '-File "C:\DevToolSetup.ps1"'
>> $now_time = Get-Date
>> $curent_time = $now_time.AddSeconds(15)
>> $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $curent_time -Once
>> $taskName = "GithubAutomation"
>> $description = "Github Configurations Automation"
>> Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -Description $description -RunLevel Highest

TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              GithubAutomation                  Ready


PS C:\>
PS C:\> Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'GithubAutomation' -Confirm:$false
Unregister-ScheduledTask : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'GithubAutomation' -Confirm:$false
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Unregister-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Unregister-ScheduledTask

PS C:\>
```

Comment: Unsure why you are getting that error, you could possibly work around it with: Get-ScheduledTask | where-object {($_.TaskName -eq "GithubAutomation")} | Unregister-ScheduledTask . Otherwise, restart the computer and try again, if that didnt work, update/repair .NET framework.

Comment: Be sure you are also elevated as administrator when you run the `Unregister-ScheduledTask` too and see if that helps. Otherwise. what value do you see when you run `$PSVersionTable` in the `PSVersion` field.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `-TaskPath` argument.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but I just had the same issue.  When I ran the power shell window with admin privileges everything was working. The error message "cannot find the file specified" is misleading in this case.